# dnsmasq - filter requests by source IP

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq

It is not recommended to answer recursive DNS queries from outside the local network.

Is there a way to make dnsmasq answer queries about specified domains (part locally part forward to another DNS server) from anywhere, but answer all queries if the request comes from local networks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running two instances of dnsmasq and doing the filtering in iptables.